# ASP.NET MVC Routing - unlimited variables tree

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have links that look like that:

```
https://myhost.com/Forums/Category/
https://myhost.com/Forums/SubCategory/
https://myhost.com/Forums/SubSubCategory/
```

Now this route config is catching above routes:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Forums_category",
    "Forums/{category}",
    new { controller = "Forums", action = "ThreadList" }
);
```

This is what I would like to use:

```
https://myhost.com/Forums/Category/SubCategory/SubSubCategory
```

And I would like it to be catched as:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Forums_category",
    "Forums/{THIS_IS_IGNORED}/{category}",
    new { controller = "Forums", action = "ThreadList" }
);
```

So, basically I would like it to catch only last variable in the link. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard (aka "catch all") parameter (prefixed by a `*` character):

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Forums_category",
    "Forums/{*category}",
    new { controller = "Forums", action = "ThreadList" }
);
```

That will cause all remaining path segments, including slashes, to be stored in `category`.

If you are only interested in the last segment you can search for the last slash character  and, if found, remove the preceding part. You probably wont like to consider trailing slashes, so trim them first.

Something like this would work:

```
category = category.TrimEnd('/');

int lastSlash = category.LastIndexOf('/');
if (lastSlash >= 0)
{
    category = category.Substring(lastSlash + 1);
}
```